# de Rham cohomology of smooth affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $U$ be a smooth variety over $\mathbb{C}$. We know that there exists a smooth compactification $X$ such that $X-U$ is a normal crossings divisor $D$ and that the de Rham cohomology of $U$ can be computed using the complex of sheaves with logarithmic differentials on $X$:
$$
H_{dR}^\ast(U)=\mathbb{H}^\ast(X, \Omega^\bullet_X(\log D))
$$

In general, one needs hypercohomology here but I am wondering if, when $U$ is affine, one simply has
$$
H^\ast_{dR}(U)=H^\ast(\Gamma(\Omega^\bullet_X(\log D))
$$ I know that this is true if one uses instead the de Rham complex $\Omega^\bullet_U$ to compute cohomology and I know that $j_\ast \Omega_U^\bullet$ and $\Omega_X^\bullet(\log D)$ are quasi-isomorphic (here $j: U \hookrightarrow X$). Is this enough to conclude?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, no. Let $X$ be an elliptic curve,  $D=p$ a point, $U=X-D$ then one sees from topology that $\dim H^1_{dR}(U)=2$. However, your proposed answer gives
$$H^1(\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X)\to \Gamma(\Omega_X^1(\log D)) 
= H^1(\mathbb{C} \stackrel{0}{\to} \mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}$$
To understand what goes wrong, note from the spectral sequence (is this OK?) we get another term $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$ which needs to be there.

Here are a few additional comments, which might help. Given a bounded complex $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$, there is a spectral sequence
$$E^{pq}= H^q(T,\mathcal{F}^p)\Rightarrow \mathbb{H}^{p+q}(T,\mathcal{F}^\bullet)$$

1. When $T=U$, and the sheaves are $\Omega_U^*$, everything is concentrated on $q=0$ line by Serre, so we get the elementary description.
2. When $T=X$ and the sheaves are $\Omega_X(\log D)^*$, we don't have such a vanishing. On the other hand, the spectral sequence degenerates at $E_1$ (Deligne), so you still don't need to do "serious" hypercohomology.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the example... I should have tried that one! So there is no way to avoid hypercohomology in the affine case?

Comment: Not really, but this is not a bad thing. I added some further comments.

Answer (score 4):

The de Rham cohomology of an affine variety $U$ is simply $H^\bullet(\Gamma(U,\Omega_U^\bullet))$ where $\Omega_U^\bullet$ is the sheaf of algebraic forms. See Grothendieck (1966), « On the de Rham cohomology of algebraic varieties », Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math., (29), p. 96.

In general, you cannot get rid of hypercohomology AND use logarithmic forms only.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that $\Omega^p_U$ is a coherent sheaf on $U$ (hence has no cohomology if $U$ is affine). However, when one computes on a smooth compactification $X$ (with $D=X\setminus U$ a divisor with strict normal crossings), one has to compute hypercohomology of a complex of coherent sheaves on $X$, which is no more affine, and the spectral sequence has no reason to be trivial (and in general, it isn't, see Donu Arapura's example).